# Many-to-many relationship: select players that are not on a specific team

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join

I tried researching this but wasn't sure what to search for. I have a `players` table and a teams table and a linker table. A player can be on multiple teams.

I need to select all players that are NOT on team XYZ.

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM players LEFT JOIN linker ON players.playerID = linker.playerID
WHERE NOT linker.teamID = 'XYZ'
```

But then a player is returned multiple times and I get false positives (say player is on team XYZ, ABC, and LMNOP - the player is returned twice).

I've tried using `GROUP BY players.playerID` which takes care of duplicates. But then I get false positives, players that are on XYZ show up in the list.

I'm sure there is something I'm missing.

(P.S. The reason I need this is to build a list of players that can be added to a team, i.e. players that are not already on the team.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM players 
WHERE playerID NOT IN
      ( SELECT playerID  
        FROM linker 
        WHERE teamID = 'XYZ'
      )
```

---

Using `LEFT JOIN - IS NULL`, your try corrected:

```
SELECT players.* 
FROM players 
  LEFT JOIN linker 
    ON  linker.playerID = players.playerID 
    AND linker.teamID = 'XYZ'
WHERE linker.playerID IS NULL
```

---

Using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM players 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM linker 
        WHERE linker.playerID = players.playerID 
          AND linker.teamID = 'XYZ'
      )
```

Comment: This works! Thanks for providing the different solutions - this helps me understand better how to interact with this kind of relationship.